# adding jquery dates to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

My form is capturing date from jquery date picker, the form works fine without the date picker but with it, it just gives this error:

```
Error: Unknown column '$time' in 'field list'
```

Below is my php & html code

```
<?php

    //form submitted
    if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    //require db details
    require_once '../dblogin.php'; 
    //set flag
    $OK = false;
    // create database connection
    $conn = new mysqli ($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Connection Failed");
    // initialize prepared statement
    $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
    // create SQL to insert task
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tasks (task_name, task_project_id, task_assignee_id, datepicker, task_created_by, task_schedule, task_duration, task_end_date, task_creation_date, task_notes, task_status)
          VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, '.$_SESSION['id'].', ?, ?, $time, NOW(), ?, ?)';

        if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
        // bind parameters and execute statement
        $stmt->bind_param('siissss', $_POST['task_name'], $_POST['task_project_id'], $_POST['task_assignee_id'], $_POST['datepicker'], $_POST['task_duration'], $_POST['task_notes'], $_POST['task_status']);
        // execute and get number of affected rows
        $stmt->execute();
            if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
            $OK = true;
            }
        }
        // redirect if successful or display error
        if ($OK) {
        header('Location: task_confirmation.php');
        exit;
        } else {
        $error = $stmt->error;
        }   
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN”
“http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd”>
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=utf-8” />
<title>Create new task</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../allcss/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<?php
require('../Login/includes/header.inc.php');
?>

<div id="content">
<?php if (isset($error)) {
  echo "<p>Error: $error</p>";
} ?>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
<div id="add">
  <p>
    <label for="task_name"class="title">Task name:</label>
    <input name="task_name" type="text" class="widebox" id="task_name">
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="title">Project: </span><select name="task_project_id" size "5">
    <?php 
    require_once '../dblogin.php'; 
    $conn = new mysqli ($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Connection Failed");
    $stmt2 = $conn->stmt_init();
    //pulls project names for the select element//
    $sql2 = 'select * from projects';
    $stmt2->prepare($sql2);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $result = $stmt2->get_result();
    while($resultRow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
    var_dump($resultRow); 
        echo "<option value='".$resultRow[project_id]."'>".$resultRow[project_name]."</option>";

    }
     $result->close();
    $stmt2->close();
    ?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="title">Assignee: </span><select name="task_assignee_id" size "5">
    <?php 
    require_once '../dblogin.php'; 
    $conn = new mysqli ($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Connection Failed");
    $stmt3 = $conn->stmt_init();
    //pulls intern names for the select element//
    $sql3 = "select * from users where user_role='INT'";
    $stmt3->prepare($sql3);
    $stmt3->execute();
    $result = $stmt3->get_result();
    while($resultRow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
    var_dump($resultRow); 
        echo "<option value='".$resultRow[person_id]."'>".$resultRow[user_name]."</option>";

    }
     $result->close();
    $stmt3->close();
    ?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="dates"class="title">Schedule for:</label>
    <input name="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="title">Duration: </span><select name="task_duration" size "1">
    <option value="00:30:00">30 minutes</option>
    <option value="01:00:00">1 hour</option>
    <option value="01:30:00">1,5 hours</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="task_notes"class="title">Additional notes:</label>
    <input name="task_notes" type="text" class="widebox" id="task_notes">
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="title">task status: </span><select name="task_status" size "1">
    <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
    <option value="Incomplete">Incomplete</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create task" id="create">
  </p>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<?php
require('../Login/includes/footer.inc.php');
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help me solve this please

Comment: When you use `'` quotes to delimit strings, variables in them will not be parsed. Use `"`

Comment: Hi @elmmm Are you sure that getting the value into the $time variable?. Try to debug. I can see that you are not getting the value for $time . Also while inserting into the database use ''(double quotes) to separate values

Comment: use prepared statements

Comment: it seems that your problem has nothing to do with datepicker at all

Comment: Go study PHP then come back when you'll have real questions. We're not free online debuggers.

Comment: @STTLCU go bully someone else, it's not like we're all experts, there is some of us who are still in school

Comment: So what, @elmmm ? the fact that you're still in school allows you to not do proper research for your own, to look for solutions? your post simply does not show proper effort. If you don't show your effort, why should we help you? Our time is limited as much as yours.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you are not using prepared statement for the `$time` value (and for $_SESSION['id'] as well).

It's either dangerous and being the very reason for the error you are getting.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tasks (task_name, task_project_id, task_assignee_id,
        datepicker, task_created_by, task_schedule, task_duration, 
        task_end_date, task_creation_date, task_notes, task_status)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?)';

if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
// bind parameters and execute statement
    $stmt->bind_param('siisissss', $_POST['task_name'], $_POST['task_project_id'],
    $_POST['task_assignee_id'], $_POST['datepicker'], $_SESSION['id'],
    $_POST['task_duration'], $time, $_POST['task_notes'], $_POST['task_status']);
```

it should be, or something like that. You need to check placeholders, types string and corresponding values yourself.

Comment: thanks. syntax error, unexpected $end <<it's giving me this error for the final </html> line

Comment: that sounds like an end parenthesis `}` is missing somewhere

Comment: @Manuel thanks it was a syntax error, it works now thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes for your query. That way `$time` isn't expanded to the variable value. You should use double Quotes (`"`) like this:

```
"INSERT INTO tasks (task_name, task_project_id, task_assignee_id, datepicker, task_created_by, task_schedule, task_duration, task_end_date, task_creation_date, task_notes, task_status)
      VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ".$_SESSION['id'].", ?, ?, $time, NOW(), ?, ?)";
```

Also I think you should use a parameter for `$_SESSION['id']` and `$time`, too, since everyting coming from the user can't really be trusted.

Comment: the error you asked about came from using a variable for the column name in single quotes, but you should also just use the prepared statement variables for all the user input, as far as I can see you already did that with `$_POST['datepicker']`